# How to use global variables in other activities

Tags: android, kotlin, global-variables

I am trying to get the global variable from one class in another class, but it gets me just an empty string.

```
class Abfahrtsmonitor : AppCompatActivity() {

    // Initializing an empty ArrayList to be filled with animals
    val Haltestellen: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val Haltestellenname = MapsAnzeigeActivity().haltestellen_name
    }
}
```

is what I want. My Class `MapsAnzeigeActivity` looks roughly like this:

```
class MapsAnzeigeActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {
    var haltestellen_name = "" 

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // ....
    }

    fun changeHaltestellen() {
        haltestellen_name = "new"
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot found global variables(top-level variables) in your code.

Comment: are they both files in different packages?

Comment: they are both in the same package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run this code:

```
val Haltestellenname = MapsAnzeigeActivity().haltestellen_name
```

It will create a new instance of `MapsAnzeigeActivity`, because default value of `haltestellen_name` is `""` that why you got an empty string.

To make a global variables (known as static variable in Java), you should use [Companion Object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html).

```
class MapsAnzeigeActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {
    companion object {
       var haltestellen_name: String
    }
}

class Abfahrtsmonitor : AppCompatActivity() {
    // Initializing an empty ArrayList to be filled with animals
    val Haltestellen: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
    val Haltestellenname = MapsAnzeigeActivity.haltestellen_name
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
class MapsAnzeigeActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {
    companion object {
       var haltestellen_name: String
    }
}

class Abfahrtsmonitor : AppCompatActivity() {

// Initializing an empty ArrayList to be filled with animals
val Haltestellen: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
val Haltestellenname = MapsAnzeigeActivity.haltestellen_name
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple choice to do this :

First you can have a singleton class like this and get the data when ever you want.

```
public class MyData {

    private ArrayList<String> data;
    private static MyData INSTANCE = new MyData();
    private MyData() {

    }

    public static MyData getInstance() {
           return INSTANCE;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getData() {
           return this.data;
    }

}
```

And when ever you want to get your data try this code :

```
MyData.getInstance().getData()
```

it will save your data in the memory and when you close your application your data will be lost.

Another options are to save your data in SharedPrefs or Sqlite, it has benefits that you can get your data even if your application closed.

Another simple way is to make your Data static like this.

```
public static ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList();
```